# Theoritical Hadoop : What happens to a NameNode in Safemode, when the exit criteria regarding number of replicated blocks is not met?

Tags: hadoop, replication

Theory: In Hadoop, I know when the Name Node enters the safe mode. I also know the exit condition concerning a minimum number of replicated blocks. What I do not understand is, what happens if that condition is not met? How will the NameNode come out of Safemode? Is there some sort of a time out?

Comment: There is the option to exit manually: `bin/hadoop dfsadmin -safemode leave`, but I guess this is not what you are looking for...

Comment: no vefthym. I know such an option exists. I'm wondering about the theoritical aspect of it.!

Comment: In theory it will be in safe mode and it won't do any replication and won't allow for any writes. If this is what you expect.

Comment: so,theoritically, the namenode is just stuck and unless forced won't be able to come out of the state it is in?